# How to get nth element from varagrs sequence

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I'm having hard time trying to get nth element from the varargs sequnce in scala. Here's my code

```
def foo(args: String*) = args.toArray(1)
```

I receive error like:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(1)
required: scala.reflect.ClassTag[?]
     def foo(args: String*) = args.toArray(1)
```

What's interesting, code like this works great:

```
def foo(args: String*) = args.toArray.apply(1)
```

I'm pretty new to scala but I thought that it should be exactly the same. Is using apply right way to  select nth element from vararg seq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `apply` on the input argument directly:

```
def foo(args: String*) = args(1)
```